# IPython Notebook and SQL: 'ImportError: No module named sql' when running '%load_ext sql'

Tags: python, pip, ipython, ipython-sql

Just set up an IPython Notebook on Ubuntu 16.04 but I can't use `%load_ext sql`.
I get: `ImportError: No module named sql`

I've tried using pip and pip3 with and without `sudo` to install ipython-sql. All 4 times it installed without issue but nothing changes on the notebook.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may be using pip from a different Python installation to the one you're running the notebook in. Check `sys.executable` in a notebook to find the Python you're running, and then use `path/to/python -m pip install ...` to install things for that.

Comment: Add the output from `which -a python` and `which -a pip`

Comment: I switched to jupyter to installed with conda. same problem. $ which -a python
`/home/hftbot/anaconda3/bin/python
/usr/bin/python`

Comment: I switched to jupyter to installed with conda. same problem. $ which -a python
`/home/hftbot/anaconda3/bin/python
/usr/bin/python`
should I mix pip into this or is there a way to do it with conda?

Comment: used conda to install mysql, pymysql. no effect.

Comment: If using conda, make sure you have jupyter installed in your conda environment, otherwise it will use the conda system one

Answer (score 8):

If you're trying to connect the IBM database and came across this problem and the above solutions couldn't do it for you, you could give this a chance. (By the way, this error usually means one of your package installations doesn't meet the requirements or more probably: you're in the wrong kernel/virtual environment and the Jupyter instance can't run your command from the specified packages.)

From JupyterLab or Jupyter Notebook go to `Kernel>Change Kernel` and change the kernel that you've installed the packages. Wait for it to establish a connection. Then use `0, 0` to restart kernel (or `Kernel>Restart Kernel`

Go to any cell and run the below commands to install packages in the current kernel.

```py
!pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.9
!pip install ibm_db_sa
!pip install ipython-sql
```

Now try
`%load_ext sql`

Comment: I had the same problem while doing the IBM DB2 Coursera assignment. The problem got solved when I replace the line starting from ! with line starting with %.  I commented the line starting from ! too. #!pip install ipython-sql
 %pip install ipython-sql

Answer (score 6):

I know it's been a long time, but I faced the same issue, and Thomas' advice solved my problem. Just outlining what I did here.

When I ran `sys.executable` in the notebook I saw `/usr/bin/python2`, while the pip I used to install the package was `/usr/local/bin/pip` (to find out what `pip` you are using, just do `which pip` or `sudo which pip` if you are installing packages system-wide). So I reinstalled `ipython-sql` using the following command, and everything worked out just fine.

`sudo -H /usr/bin/python2 -m pip install ipython-sql`

This is odd since I always install my packages using `pip`. I'm wondering maybe there's something special about the magic functions in Jupyter.

Comment: It worked for me using python2, now jupyter load sql

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer will be (very) late to contribute to the discussion but maybe it will help someone. I found out what worked for me by following Thomas, who commented above. However, with a bit of a caveat, that I was using *pyenv* to setup and manage python on my local machine.

So when running `sys.executable` in a jupyter notebook cell I found out my python path was `/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.2.8/libexec/bin/python3.9`, while I expected it to be somewhere along the lines of `'/Users/<USER_NAME>/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/bin/python'`.

This error was attributed to me having installed jupyter through command `brew install jupyter` instead of `pyenv exec pip install jupyter`. I proceeded to uninstall jupyter with brew and then executing the second command, which now got jupyter up and running!

(note that you would first have to have *pyenv* setup properly).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you're using different IPython Notebook kernel other than which you've installed `ipython-sql` in.
IPython Notebook can have more than one kernel. If it is the case, make sure you're in the right place first.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you installed jupyter, is where jupyter loads exts.
You are using the jupyter installed outside of virtual environment,
then activated virtual environment,
then installed `ipython-sql`,
then trying to `load_ext` from different level.

Just deactivate the virtual environment, install `ipython-sql`, and then activate the environment.

If you want to install `ipython-sql` only in the virtual environment, then at least you need to install jupyter inside the virtual environment too.
Both puppies should be in the same level.